# Could we really charge metal plates using microwaves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, heat, microwaves

While skimming through [Dielectric heating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating), I read that they use microwaves to charge the plates. How do they do that?

Comment: Hello Abdel, Perhaps Any reference would be good, so that many users could try to answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  This is how a [microwave ovens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_ovens) work (at least when you put metal in them).  Microwave ovens emit electromagnetic radiation in the microwave region (roughly $2.4 \, \mathrm{GHz}$)
Metal plates in a microwave oven act as [antennas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_%28radio%29) and the electromagnetic radiation induces a huge electric current.

If you are looking for specific details on how current is induced, any antenna theory will help.  If you're interested in the power transfer, check out [wireless power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power).